# shows different price in “Confirm your in-app purchase” dialog ios

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

Adding in-app purchase for a ios app. I could successfully purchase the product but "Confirm Your In-App Purchase" dialog always shows extra price compared to my formatted localised price.

Example: A localised price for a product is 39.99 Euros, but when in the confirmation dialogue box, the price of the product is increased to 41.73 Euros.

Thanks in advance for any solutions for this issue.

Comment: does this have something to do with apple recently changing app prices to account for VAT in EU? How do you get the `39.99` in the first place?

Comment: I was thinking the same. FYI: http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/jan/08/apple-ios-app-prices-iceland

Comment: Same thing happened to me, product.price is 0.99€ in Tier 1 (After the app store change), but when it is going to charge money it says 1.56€
It is confusing, I would like to know what is gonna happen with this

Comment: For tier value 50,i am getting formatted localised price 39.99 Euros you can also refer this link for more details(http://grab.by/DHUE).

Answer (score 2):

Actually it seems this is only happening in the sandbox. So the production is fine. 
I've tested it on the NL and FR store. Another dev confirmed the same from the DE store.

If you have access to the Apple developer forums, more details in this thread: 
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/259099?tstart=0

---

**Outdated?**

Still researching a proper solution but here is the first part of this answer.

Apple is required by EU regulation to charge tax based on where the customer is located, not the company's Euro HQ.

An in-app purchase of € 3,99 (Tier 4) is now € 4,34 in NL.

*news source: http://www.theverge.com/2015/1/8/7518085/apple-app-store-price-increase-europe-canada*

---

Still working on how to show the customer the price + tax.

SkProduct does not seem to have a tax property so it might need to be calculated. There's no property that provides the tax value.

[image: SKProduct properties]

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/index.html

Comment: This make sense (sort of)... But, receiving the product price as a value and then charging more than that is confusing. And if the taxes raise again then we have to recalculate and it will be bad until the app update...
I tried buying a 0.99 purchase, and they ask for 0.99 as usual (10 cents more, but same as product.price)
I think Apple should give more info about this

Comment: Have you found any information about it ? It seems that this thread is the only one talking about it on google..

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue with my app. I don't think it has anything to do with the new prices, at least it shouldn't. Because of the aforementioned EU regulation, app prices in NL increased from €0,79 to €0,99 for tier 1. This is because of the higher VAT rate (21% in NL). This should cover it and there is no need to add another charge on the €0,99 price tag for taxes. I am really curious about the cause of this behavior. Below an example of another app.

[image: Alertview 1]

[image: Alertview 2]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding was that Apple raised the prices in those price tiers to reflect the Change in tax laws that went into effect on Jan 1st. The difference in different tax rates for each EU country is also illustrated by the different "Proceeds, Net Commission" seen on the [Pricing Matrix.](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/33.1.0.11.5.0.9.3.1.1.3.0.13.1.1.11.1.17.3)

I have also tried a few other countries and it seems like the % they are applying is pretty arbitrary.

There was no communication regarding an additional tax that would be applied to users.

Answer (score 0):

At least I am not the only one with this problem.

By the way, I think it is a bug because the difference between the prices makes no sense.

I report the current values. On the left the price retrieved (Which is the correct one), on the right the price asked at the moment of purchase.

```
0.99 euro -> 1.56 euro
4.99 euro -> 5.21 euro
9.99 euro -> 10.43 euro
14.99 euro -> 14.77 euro
19.99 euro -> 19.99 euro
20.99 euro -> 20.86 euro
39.99 euro -> 43.47 euro
74.99 euro -> 73.90 euro
```

These values have no constant relationship... that's why I think it is a bug.

The test was done using a test account for italian store.

Answer (score 0):

Since 1 January in Europe apple increase prices based on where you are.

Even so, the first time shows me a price without taxes, and the second time and the following show me the prices with taxes.

[image: First time]
[image: Second time]

Im sure its a bug from apple.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it seems it solved now. Both alert views show the correct amount. It probably was a bug, because I did not change anything.