# SKProduct price differs in In-App-Purchase confirmation

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, storekit

I have some strange behavior with IAP (Sandbox). At first I thought I made a mistake, but then I loaded another project (see images) with IAP and it shows the same behavior. In my app I provide the possibility to buy an upgrade. I the user presses the "Buy" button, an alert view pops up that asks if the user wants to buy the upgrade for €1,99. If the user wants that, the purchase process starts and another alert view pops up, which is a confirmation for the purchase. But this confirmation shows another price (€2,34). Does anyone have an idea why this is?

Thanks in advance!

[image: First alertview]
[image: Second "confirmation" alertview]

Comment: Where are you getting the value for "Buy this for..."? Are you asking the SKProduct for the localized price or are you loading it from some source other than Apple?

Comment: I believe the added amount accounts for the VAT.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27877516/2274694

Comment: @BradBrighton I am using the price property of the SKProduct. I also read the post that was linked by Lyndsey. I do not think it is the VAT, because it is 21% in NL, which will result in a price of €2,41. Furthermore, the price table shows a price of €1,99 for tier 2 and also states that this is including taxes.

Comment: Hmmm... the only other thing I might consider is the possibility that the locale being used for the localizedPrice isn't what you think it is (or that Apple's recent price-tier changes aren't what you expect). Interestingly, the current Pricing Matrix available under agreements in iTunes Connect (for me, a US dev, though I don't think it makes a difference) doesn't appear to show 2.34 as value for any zone. [EDIT] Maybe the sandbox isn't kept as immediately current to the production pricing changes?

Answer (score 0):

The information in the second pop up is correct one. And the pop up that you are showing at first has kinda invalid information. The price 1.99 is actually USD price. And the '€' symbol must be concatenated by you in the string.

It happens because of two reasons:

1. When device has no Apple Id logged in (for in-app purchases). Therefore `SKProduct`'s `price` property will have price in USD.
2. When device is logged in with an Apple ID that belongs to a user of other country than yours. `SKProduct`'s `price` property will have price of that country.

You can format the string that works for every country. Here is a code snippet that will create such string for you.

```
public extension SKProduct {

    public var localizedPrice: String? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.locale = self.priceLocale
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return numberFormatter.string(from: self.price)
    }
}
```

You can use `localizedPrice` property now on `SKProduct` object without writing yourself €.

Answer (score 0):

Apple returns fixed price for testers. Price should be correct in production.