# InApp-Purchase having two different prices

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I’ve got several InApp-Purchases in iTunesConnect and I do receive their data through my application. All the data is received and everything seems to work correctly. The prices are between Tier 1 and Tier 3. Everything seems perfectly fine. (See Screenshot #1)

But when I want to purchase these, I do always get a different (higher) price. (See Screenshot #2)

Am I doing something wrong? Does this have to do with the current tax increase in Europe? The code I do use for printing the price on top of my buttons:

```
NSNumberFormatter *priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
for (SKProduct *p in _products) {
    [priceFormatter setLocale:p.priceLocale];
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",p.localizedTitle,[priceFormatter stringFromNumber:p.price]];
}
```

The prices do not increase by a certain percentage, though (which contradicts the tax idea):

**Tier 1 - 0,99€ -> 1,56€**

**Tier 2 - 1,99€ -> 2,34€**

**Tier 3 - 2,99€ -> 3,12€**

**Edit #1:** Apparently the price changes randomly. [I also recorded a video of the phenomeno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXwpIgjSKso)n. You can see that the price is loaded from the AppStore in the beginning. This does happen in the simulator and on the device as well. AppStore account is a sandbox account on both.

**Edit #2:** I also checked the pricing matrix for the higher values. They do not appear in the whole matrix. So I guess it is not the Sandbox sending me the value for a wrong EU country.

**Edit #3:** I created a new Sandbox user for the **United States Appstore**. Now the prices seem to be correct constantly (tried it ~15 times). What does this tell us? Is the European Sandbox buggy or will my customers in spe in Europe see wrong prices?

[image: Screenshot of shop with correct prices]
[image: Screenshot of dialog with wrong price]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877516/shows-different-price-in-confirm-your-in-app-purchase-dialog-ios

Answer (score 0):

In my case the first time show me the price without taxes, and the following times show the price with taxes

Edit: the taxes are wrong implemented

Comment: Can you confirm this for multiple price tiers? This was my first thought, but apparently the percentage value does change quite a bit between the tiers.

Comment: I confirm that occurs in all tiers (always in sandbox). They also say that the percentages is bad implemented, as in 1.99€ tier adds approximately 0.40€ (correct) and 2.99€ tier adds about 0.15€, which indicates that is wrong implemented